# Hp laptop stuck in airplane mode after suspend

Tags: wireless, suspend, hp, airplane-mode

I have an HP laptop with ubuntu 18.04 installed on it. 
Every time i suspend ubuntu, once i turn it on the laptop is in airplane mode. I am unable to disable the airplane mode it says use hardware key. But using hardware key(F12). Doesn't work. I have searched for hours and none of the solutions work.I know this question has been answered a couple of times, but those solutions didn't work for me. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I already checked both these questions. None of the solutions worked for me

Comment: Sorry neither worked for you. I've retracted my close vote.